# Find and remove element with specific content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have lots of `<p> &nbsp </p>` tags in the middle of description contents. i want to find and remove the tags containing only `&nbsp`. The description container has a class-name `desc_container`.

Here is the example of container,

```
<div class="desc_container">
    <p> Some contents! <p>
    <p> &nbsp </p>
    <p> Again some contents! <p>
    <p> &nbsp </p>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      // This will give me all the <p> tags
      $('.desc_container').find('p');

      // This is what i want
      $('.desc_container').find('p').containsOnly('&nbsp');
    }
</script>
```

Appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Please include some of your html code and show us what you have tried to create this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the `$(this).html().trim() === '&nbsp;'` inside the loop for each `<p>` element and remove the `<p>` element. You can use browser's `inspect element` option in the below example for further verification.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.desc_container p').each(function(){
    if($(this).html().trim() === '&nbsp;'){
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desc_container">
 <p> This is a example </p> <p> &nbsp </p> for some content here <p> test data</p><p> &nbsp </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a gem! Thank yu.

Comment: @srihs glad to help!!

Answer (score 1):

The [`:contains()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp) selector selects elements containing the specified string. The following code will remove the `<p>` tag which contains `&nbsp` and might have other content too.

```
$("p:contains(&nbsp)").remove();
```

If you want to remove the `<p>` which contain only `&nbsp` then you can loop `<p>` tag and remove whose value is `&nbsp`

```
$('p').each(function(){
   if($(this).text().trim() == "&nbsp"){
       $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `find` since you can simply select all `<p>` tags inside the `desc_container`.

Just use the following selector: `$('.desc_container p')` or `jQuery('.desc_container p')` if you haven't mapped the `jQuery` object to `$`.

This will return you all the `Nodes`, which can be looped with jQuery's `each` method and then removed with `.remove()`. Also, make sure to `trim` the string before comparing.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.desc_container p').each(function() {
    if($(this).html().trim() === '&nbsp;'){
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desc_container">
 <p>Text</p> <p> &nbsp </p><p>Text</p><p> &nbsp </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".desc_container p").each(function(){
      if($(this).text().trim() == "") {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desc_container">
    <p> Some contents! <p>
    <p> &nbsp </p>
    <p> Again some contents! <p>
    <p> &nbsp </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#deleteEmpty").on('click', function() {
  $(".desc_container p").each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    if ($element.html().trim() === "&nbsp;") {
      $element.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.desc_container p {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="desc_container">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Sample text here</p>
  <p> &nbsp; </p>
  <p>Sample text here</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Sample text here</p>
  <p>Sample text here</p>
  <p>Sample text here</p>
  <p> &nbsp; </p>
  <p></p>
  <p>Sample text here</p>
</div>

<button id="deleteEmpty">Delete empty `p` tags</button>
```